# Diagnose Power Supply Failure?

Tags: windows-7, power-supply

I have a single 500W supply powering my home server. I think I have derived that a hardware failure is the problem. The following symptoms are prevalent across multiple installations of Win7.

**Symptoms:**

1. Random power-off every once in a while
2. Sometime takes a few presses of power button to power on
3. AVG Antivirus and Catalyst Control Center throw URLMON.dll errors
   ([Error Link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/urlmondll-causing-many-programs-to-crash/cda9a6cb-cf51-499c-8855-45c97110eafe))
4. HTML-based content tries and fails to download instead of displaying
   properly. (AVG and CCC most commonly)

I ran `sfc /scannow` in hopes of cleaning up some file system corruption. Here is my log: [Log Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13785294/PasteBin/log.txt)

**System Info:**
[image]

Does anyone else see this as PSU failure? Or is there another problem I'm not considering?

Comment: Motherboard failure is certainly possible, but there's not enough information to know what the cause is. Have you attempted replacing the component you suspect to see if the problem is gone?

Comment: I don't think it's a power supply issue, at least not from the information you've provided. Check Eventviewer for some information on the sudden power-offs (I've also had a power supply take a couple presses after a sudden crash, if you try immediately after.) I see this as possibly 2 or more separate issues, not likely related to the PSU.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- system does not power off unexpectedly when it has a light or no load
- the CPU tempurature is "reasonable" (less than 70-80 C for most chips) under load
- the combined motherboard + graphics card power draw maximum is within the specs of the PSU

Then the likelyhood the PSU is the source of your PC problems is way down on the list of probable causes.

The failure pattern/symptoms described do not strongly indicate the PSU as the root cause of the failures, but also don't preclude that. The best chance of resolving the problem lies in finding a reproducible test case where the problem always/frequently occurs. In comments below, it's mentioned that the system is used for Gaming. Try looking for some simple, strongly correlated events. For example:

- the system doesn't crash when it's sitting idle
- the system only crashes when it's running sims 3

That will help to narrow down the possible cause.

Comment: I booted and performed a Memtest for 12 hours yesterday with no problems. And this issue has been persistent even after a fresh install of Win7.
I have been monitoring CPU temps almost constantly and it never exceeds 69C under load (Gaming).

Comment: *Updating post with system information*

Comment: Do you mention Gaming because (A) crashes tend to happen when it is being used for that, or (B) Gaming simply a convenient load generator? If (A), GPUs can also be a source of overheating and other problems. As mentioned above, can you narrow down the circumstances when the problem occurs?

Comment: StackExchange/SuperUser isn't the right place to get interactive break/fix help. I've pulled back and just answered the "is it the PSU" question.